# How to get json tree value to DataGridView

Tags: json, vb.net, datagridview

I need to get the `EUR price` from json source API page https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/axie-infinity which is in some kind of '`tree`' results.

The `Rank` `market_cap_rank` I'm able to get but `current_price` I'm not able.

My Code:

```
Public Class JsonResponse

        <JsonProperty("market_cap_rank")>
        Public Property _rank As String

        <JsonProperty("current_price")>
        Public Property _cPrice As String

    End Class

    Public Sub getRankAXS()
    Try
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True

        Dim _urlAXS As String = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/axie-infinity" '&format=json"

        Dim _req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(_urlAXS)
        _req.Proxy = Nothing
        _req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.81 Safari/537.36"

        Dim _resp As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = _req.GetResponse
        Dim streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(_resp.GetResponseStream())
        Dim rank_source As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd
        Dim _rankResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JsonResponse)(rank_source)

        Dim vRank = _rankResults._rank
        Dim vPrice = _rankResults._cPrice

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Nothing
        For Each item As DataGridViewRow In dgvMain.Rows
            row = item
            dgvMain.Rows(17).Cells(0).Value = vRank
            dgvMain.Rows(17).Cells(4).Value = vPrice 

        Next
        dgvMain.Refresh()
        _runningThreads.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

The Source in short:

```
"country_origin": "",
"genesis_date": null,
"contract_address": "0xbb0e17ef65f82ab018d8edd776e8dd940327b28b",
"sentiment_votes_up_percentage": 86.04,
"sentiment_votes_down_percentage": 13.96,
"market_cap_rank": 35,
"coingecko_rank": 282,
"coingecko_score": 34.249,
"developer_score": 0.0,
"community_score": 12.533,
"liquidity_score": 74.834,
"public_interest_score": 4.85,
    "market_data": {
        "current_price": {
        "aed": 253.89,
        "dot": 3.081598,
        "eos": 26.36419,
        "eth": 0.022493,
        "eur": 60.44,
        "gbp": 51.16,
        }

    }
"total_value_locked": null,
"mcap_to_tvl_ratio": null,
"fdv_to_tvl_ratio": null,
"roi": null,
```

SO under `_cPrice` I need to get the `=>market_data => current_price => eur`

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a cool feature called Paste JSON as Classes that can be found under Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes. I cannot paste the example because the incoming payload is too large.

However, once you get the classes defined, you can then deserialize the object using the following:

```vb
Dim payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(rank_source)
Dim eurMarketDataCurrentPrice = payload.market_data.current_price.eur
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/moVuMl

Comment: ok I will check then mark answer for you give me a minute

Comment: Root 'object is not defined' so it doesnt work :(

Comment: @MiningChamber - Did you bother to check the fiddle that contains the object definitions or to follow the instructions for Paste JSON as Classes?